# how to save the current playlist in Cantata as mu3?

Tags: playlists

How can I save my current selected music files in my Cantata playlist as mu3?

I discovered Cantata as new music player and so far I like it. Now I have selected several files for a zoom meeting tomorrow. How can I save this playlist as e.g. mu3 so I can reload it if I should accidentally destroy my current selection?

All I have found so far talks about generating dynamic playlists or loading already generated playlists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mark all pieces in your current playlist, press `ctrl` & `S` keys (saving, eh! Who would have thought that!) and in the little pop up give your list a name.

To play this list go to the playlist menue and under "saved playlists" you click on the list you just saved and choos play and replace current list"

And - voilá - there you are!